# Keycloak refreshing with every navigation in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-sign-on, keycloak

[image]

Hello Stackoverflow community

Thank you for your help. I have a build a react app using keycloak as a identity manager for authentication. One of the problem I am seeing in my app is every time I navigate to a different route, I am redirected to keycloak first and then navigated to the component. This is bad experience and I would like keycloak to know its state as the user uses the app and make this a seamless experience.
How do make it not refresh/check for authentication once the user has authenticated?

App.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NavMain from "./components/NavMain";
import HomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import SecuredPage from "./pages/Securedpage";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboardpage";
import Account from "./pages/AccountPage";
import PricingPage from "./pages/PricingPage";

function App() {


 return (
   <div>

           <BrowserRouter>
             <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                  <Route path="about" element={ <AboutPage />}  />
                  <Route path="pricing" element={ <PricingPage />}  />
                  <Route path="app" element={ <SecuredPage />}  >
                    <Route index element={ <Dashboard />}  />
                    <Route path="dashboard" element={ <Dashboard />}  />
                    <Route path="account" element={ <Account />}  />
                  </Route>
            </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>


    </div>
 );
}
export default App;
```

SecuredApp.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import keycloak from "../Keycloak";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboardpage";
import AboutPage from "./AboutPage";
import PrivateRoutes from "../helpers/PrivateRoutes";

import NavHomePage from "../components/NavHomePage";

const Loading = () => <div>Loading...</div>
const Secured = () => {

 return (
   <div>
     <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}
     initOptions={{
        onLoad: "login-required",
      }}
      LoadingComponent={<Loading />} >
        <NavHomePage/>
      </ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </div>
 );
};

export default Secured;
```

Dashboard.JS

```
import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {

 return (
   <div>
     <h1 className="text-green-800 text-4xl">Dashboard</h1>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

NavHomePage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

const NavHomePage = () => {
 const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();

 function logoutHelper(){
   console.log("login clicked");
   keycloak.logout();
 };


 return (
 <div>
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Hype</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                      <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/app/dashboard">dashboard</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/app/account">Account</Nav.Link>
                      </Nav>
                      <Nav className="ml-auto">

                        {!!keycloak.authenticated && (
                             <Nav.Link onClick={() => logoutHelper()}>
                             Logout ({keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username})</Nav.Link>)}
                      </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
    </Navbar>
    <Outlet />
    </div>
 );
};

export default NavHomePage;
```

Is there a setting where we can tell keycloak how to not refresh?